# Angular2/4 app to display forms based on JSON data using ngFor and ngIf only. Could it work?

Tags: json, forms, angular, angular2-forms

I have to build an Angular application that has a single task: It receives JSON data that describe a form structure, e.g.:

```
{
  "textbox": {
    "type": "string",
    "name": "name",
    "maxlength": 30,
    "description": "Full Name"
  },
  "textbox": {
    "type": "string",
    "name": "email",
    "maxlength": 40,
    "description": "Email"
  },
  "date": {
    "name": "birthdate",
    "description": "Birthdate"
  },
  "checkbox": {
    "name": "subscribe",
    "options": [
      "Yes",
      "No"
    ],
    "default": "No",
    "description": "Subscribe?"
  },
  "button": {
    "type": "submit",
    "description": "Send"
  }
}
```

And it should display it: (All forms are different with varying elements.)

[image: form preview]

I'm relatively new to Angular and my initial approach would be to create a simple template that has an ngFor in it, and inside many ngIfs (one for text fileds, one for text area, another for radio button, and so on...) that examine for the "type" of the given form element, and if there is a match, it gets displayed with its attributes written in the JSON.

Is it a good idea to start like this, or should I first learn some more Angular to be able to come up with a more professional solution?

Are things like dynamic and reactive forms in Angular for this purpose, or which part of Angular should I have a deeper understanding in for this task?

Comment: Use angular formly.  https://ng2.angular-formly.com/guides/introductory-example.html

Comment: Yes, when starting with a new framework t is always a good idea to start with the basics and then add complexity as you go forward. Starting out too complex could lead to frustration and wasted time. That said, check this out: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: I took the time to read the basics and relevant parts of the Angular docs and now that I have a better understanding of its logic (directives, objects, dynamic forms, etc.) I started to implement my app using _ng-formly_ which (and a big thanks for recommending it!) seems to be a superior module for this purpose. It helps me a lot in building up my application and while I'm playing with it, I also gather a lot of experience with Angular. :)

Comment: 'ng-formly' is actually a good candidate to solve this kind of tasks. You can also take a look at [ng-dynamic-forms](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms) which is based on the official Angular dynamic forms guide. Hope it will also help you to better understand Angular ecosystem around the form-building.